# Эффект набора текста при переключении слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В слайдере необходимо реализовать эффект "набора текста" при переключении слайдов. Для самого слайдера использую Slick Slider. Вот рабочий пример http://test2.hotweb.com.ua/webbit/ находится в вверху страницы.

HTML код:

```
<div class="header-slider-wrap">

        <div class="header-slider">
            <div class="slider-nav__left nav-btn-slider">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 477.175 477.175"><path d="M145.188 238.575l215.5-215.5c5.3-5.3 5.3-13.8 0-19.1s-13.8-5.3-19.1 0l-225.1 225.1c-5.3 5.3-5.3 13.8 0 19.1l225.1 225c2.6 2.6 6.1 4 9.5 4s6.9-1.3 9.5-4c5.3-5.3 5.3-13.8 0-19.1l-215.4-215.5z"/></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-nav__right nav-btn-slider">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 477.175 477.175"><path d="M360.73 229.075l-225.1-225.1c-5.3-5.3-13.8-5.3-19.1 0s-5.3 13.8 0 19.1l215.5 215.5-215.5 215.5c-5.3 5.3-5.3 13.8 0 19.1 2.6 2.6 6.1 4 9.5 4 3.4 0 6.9-1.3 9.5-4l225.1-225.1c5.3-5.2 5.3-13.8.1-19z"/></svg>
            </div>

            <ul class="slider-item-list">
                <li class="slider-item one">
                    <div class="slider-text-wrap">
                        <div class="slider-text slider-text-one after-line" id='slider_text_one' data-text='Текст номер 1'></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="slider-item two">
                    <div class="slider-text-wrap">
                        <div class="slider-text slider-text-two after-line" id='slider_text_two' data-text='Текст номер 2'></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="slider-item three">
                    <div class="slider-text-wrap">
                        <div class="slider-text slider-text-three after-line" id='slider_text_three' data-text='Текст номер 3'></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
```

JS код:

```
printTextSlider();

function printTextSlider() {
    var $btn = $('.nav-btn-slider'),
            $ul       = $('.slider-item-list'),
            $activeLi = $ul.find('.slick-active'),
            $text     = $activeLi.find('.slider-text');

    $text.addClass('is-active');
    printText($text);


    $btn.on('click', function() {

        var $activeLi = $ul.find('.slick-active'),
                $siblings = $activeLi.siblings().find('.slider-text'),
                $text     = $activeLi.find('.slider-text'),
                id        = $text.attr('id');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $siblings.removeClass('is-active');
        }, 1000);


        $text.addClass('is-active');
        printText($('#'+id));


    });
}

function printText(el) {
    var a = el.data('text');
    a = a.split('');

    console.log(a);

    el.text('');

    var c = a.length;

    j = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        if(j < c) {
            el.text(el.text() + a[j]);
            j++;
        } 
        else {
            el.removeClass('after-line');
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Стили(Sass) применяемые для текста:

```
.slider-text-wrap {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 230px;
}


.slider-text {
  font-size: 36px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  opacity: 0;

  &.is-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.after-line {
  &:after {
    content: '_';
  }
}
```

**Проблема**: при переключении слайдов, текст выводиться некорректно.